# require_once não funciona

Tags: php, array, classes, undefined, require

Estou tentando dar

```
require_once
```

num Arquivo PHP que tem uma classe.

O Arquivo que estou tentando incluir no PHP com a classe possui apenas um array com dados de configuração, porém não consigo acessa-lo devidamente.

```
class CoreDatabase {

    public $database;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once('aps/config/database.php');
        $this->database = new PDO($db_data['default']['driver'] . ':host=' . $db_data['default']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db_data['default']['name'], $db_data['default']['user'], $db_data['default']['password']);

        $statement = $this->database->prepare('select * from tablex');

        $statement->execute();
        echo var_dump($statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        echo var_dump($this->database);
        echo var_dump($data);
        echo var_dump($statement);
    }
```

**Editado**
Galera, eu resolvi brevemente, desculpem o incomodo.

Enfim, eu fiz o

```
require_once
```

dentro do construtor da classe, e deu certo, agora eu atribuo

```
$db_data
```

para um atributo e tenho tudo dentro da classe.

Comment: PS: Quando leio os logs de erro, dizem que PHP Notice:  Undefined variable.

Comment: `$db_data` veio da onde?

Comment: Vem do require_once require_once('aps/config/database.php');

Comment: Comentário para a sua resposta: Se você quiser, você pode lidar com o erro verificando o retorno da função `require_once`.   `$retorno = require_once('aps/config/database.php');   if ($retorno === false) {  echo "Error." }`.

Comment: Você pode [responder sua própria pergunta e aceitá-la como resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Assim, fica mais claro para quem ver sua pergunta mais tarde. E, ainda te possibilita a ganhar mais pontos.

Answer (score 3):

Se `$db_data` é a variável de configuração que vem de `aps/config/database.php` ela deve ser passada como argumento no construtor dessa forma a classe consegue acessar ela.

Mude:

```
public function __construct() {
```

Para:

```
public function __construct($db_data) {
```

Na hora instanciar essa classe lembre de passar a variável.

```
$dbCore = new CoreDatabase($db_data);
```

Comment: Obrigado rray, é uma opção, porém eu não poderia estar passando como parâmetro, eu queria fazer algo mais parecido com a estrutura do CodeIgniter, sabe? Porém é uma opção, obrigado!

Comment: @instalaçãoplanejamento o CodeIgniter da um include dentro de um método olha o [código](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB.php#L57)

Comment: Sim sim! Percebi isso agora! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Mano é fato que tem erro, só tem que o require_once produz um tratamento de erro que encerra o script, usa include_once no lugar que ele vai te exibir o erro e você vê o que tá errado e corrige, ex:

```
include_once "aps/config/database.php";
```

E tem mais, declare fora da class, ex:

```
include_once "aps/config/database.php";
class CoreDatabase {}
```

Comment: O `require_once` também produz uma mensagem de erro. A diferença que é que ele produz um erro **fatal** que parará o script (`E_COMPILE_ERROR`) enquanto que o `include_once` ou gerará apenas um aviso (`E_WARNING`).